# How to update one array from Another Array

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays

Here is my Old Array 1 saved in Document Dir and Array 2 is fetch from server. Here I have to update respective data of Array 1 after fetch data from server with Array 2.

[image]

And After Update Array 1 will be :

[image]

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried? What did it do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to compare the two arrays and update the local one. Keep in mind that this code could probably be optimized, but it should at least give you an idea of how to do it :-)

```
- (NSArray *)updateArray:(NSArray *)currentArray withData:(NSArray *)webServerData {
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Loop through each NSDictionary in the local array
    for (NSDictionary *dict in currentArray) {
        NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"NAME"];
        BOOL updateDict = NO;

        //For each NSDictionary, loop through the NSDictionaries in the array from the web server
        for (NSDictionary *dict2 in webServerData) {

            //If the name in the local dict is the same as the one in the one from the web server, check if the age is different
            if ([name isEqualToString:[dict2 objectForKey:@"NAME"]]) {
                if ([[dict objectForKey:@"AGE"] integerValue] != [[dict2 objectForKey:@"AGE"] integerValue]) {

                    //If the age is different, add the new dictionary
                    [arr addObject:dict2];
                    updateDict = YES;
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        //Add the dict from local array if no new data was found in the web server array
        if (!updateDict) {
            [arr addObject:dict];
        }
    }

    return [arr copy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to a plist that is included in your bundle. If you need the plist to be editable, you need to create your own plist in the documents directory and work with that one.

Flow:

1. At first launch of your app, get the plist from the bundle and create a new plist that is saved in the Documents directory, with the contents from the original plist.
2. Whenever you need data from the plist, use the one you created on launch and stored in the Documents directory. Never use the one from the bundle again.
3. When you need to update the plist, update the one you stored in Documents.

Comment: I am well aware about to save file and retrieve data from Doc Dir. Here I need only the sort and smart way to map two different array only, I update My Question, could be It will help you to get my actual requirement. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, so your question now (how to merge two arrays with custom objects) is totally different from your original (how to update a local plist file). What you need to do is iterate through one array and compare each object with objects from the other array. If your data structure is like the sketch, Jorn's answer is one possibility. I would recommend you spend a little more time phrasing your question the next time :-)